# Adding margin-bottom to border-collaps table

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a table that is very similar to this same code found in the fiddle:

```
 <table id="table">
    <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="table-data cell-counter">1</td>
      <td class="table-data cell-description">HelloHello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="table-data cell-counter">2</td>
      <td class="table-data cell-description">HelloHello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="table-data cell-counter">3</td>
      <td class="table-data cell-description">HelloHello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="table-data cell-counter">10</td>
      <td class="table-data cell-description">HelloHello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="table-data cell-counter">11</td>
      <td class="table-data cell-description">HelloHello</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <style>
    #table {
      width: 100%;
        color: black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }

    .table-row td:nth-child(1),
    .table-row th:nth-child(1) {
        width: 5%;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .table-row td:nth-child(2),
    .table-row th:nth-child(2) {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .table-body tr:nth-child(2n + 4) {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    .table-body tr:nth-child(2n + 5) {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }

    .cell-counter {
        word-wrap: break-word;
      font-weight: bold;
        font-size: $larger-font-size;
    }

    .cell-description {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0xkvz2p1/18/

For the first 3 places I want to have a `margin-bottom` so that the rows have a little bit of space between them.

Howeverbut, since I have to use `border-collapse` for the rows to have the right color without any space between the `<td>`, the margin doesn't have any effect. If I insert a `<div>` before the `<td>`, the alignment is lost (for example, the position goes from 1 digit to 2 digits 9-10).

Does anyone have a nice solution to my problem?

Comment: Give an id to the divs with the cell-counter (the ones you want more space) and make the id specify `padding-bottom: 5px;` or whatever size you would like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello i solved it by doing kind of what Christopher Bennett mentioned in the comments.

i just put a `<div>` inside the top 3(colored) `<td>` and put the coloring on the `<div>` and then a `margin-bottom` on the `<div>`

Like this

```
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>
    <div className="table-row-margin">
       <span>HelloHello</span>
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

And the css

```
.table-row-margin {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5%;
}

.table-body tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) div:first-child {
    background-color: #FFF45E;
}

.table-body tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) div:first-child {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.table-body tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) div:first-child {
    background-color: #FFC933;
}
.table-body tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) div:first-child,
.table-body tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) div:first-child,
.table-body tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) div:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try rowspan.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Comment: I dont want any td to go on multiple rows i want each row to have some margin at the bottom